# How we can get java object value( url ) in Thymeleaf conditional operator?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I want to put one condition in thymeleaf, If my object contain url so i want to print anchor tag with Url so i can open it and if not, then a message should be display.

```
<span th:utext="${#strings.contains({resultModel.results},'s3')} ? '<a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;${resultModel.results}&quot; >URL</a>' : ${resultModel.results}"></span>
```

I want to get URL as a java object in href. Please suggest `href=&quot;${resultModel.results}&quot;`

If i use `href=&quot;http://google.co.in&quot;` so it is working but while using `href=&quot;${resultModel.results}&quot;` i am not getting value.

Note: In Above html code else condition is working and getting message as a results.

Comment: proper code view

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try and combine that logic... Avoid putting html in html by just splitting the tags out the inner html into its own tags.

```
<th:block th:with="condition=${#strings.contains(resultModel.results, 's3')}">
    <a th:if="${condition}" target="blank" th:href="${resultModel.results}">URL</a>
    <span th:unless="${condition}" th:text="${resultModel.results}" />
</th:block>
```